# sfdisk failing to write partition to disk

Tags: ubuntu, sd-card, bootable

I am trying make my microSD card bootable to Ubuntu. I am trying to use `sfdisk` to create the partitions. When I do that this is the error I am getting:

```
Using sfdisk to create partition layout
-----------------------------
Checking that no-one is using this disk right now ...
OK

Disk /dev/sdb: 30436 cylinders, 64 heads, 32 sectors/track
Old situation:
Warning: The partition table looks like it was made
  for C/H/S=*/255/63 (instead of 30436/64/32).
For this listing I'll assume that geometry.
Units = mebibytes of 1048576 bytes, blocks of 1024 bytes, counting from 0

   Device Boot Start   End    MiB    #blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1         4  30436- 30433-  31162880    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sdb2         0      -      0          0    0  Empty
/dev/sdb3         0      -      0          0    0  Empty
/dev/sdb4         0      -      0          0    0  Empty
New situation:
Units = mebibytes of 1048576 bytes, blocks of 1024 bytes, counting from 0

   Device Boot Start   End    MiB    #blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *     1     96     96      98304    e  W95 FAT16 (LBA)
/dev/sdb2         0      -      0          0    0  Empty
/dev/sdb3         0      -      0          0    0  Empty
/dev/sdb4         0      -      0          0    0  Empty
/dev/sdb: Input/output error

sfdisk: Failed writing the partition on /dev/sdb
Re-reading the partition table ...
/dev/sdb: Input/output error
Error closing /dev/sdb
If you created or changed a DOS partition, /dev/foo7, say, then use dd(1)
to zero the first 512 bytes:  dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/foo7 bs=512 count=1
(See fdisk(8).)
```

Any ideas what would be the issue? The disk is writable.

Answer (score 0):

Are you root when running this command? Make sure when executing these types of commands that you elevate your permissions using `sudo`, which you typically need to have to perform these types of tasks.

#### Example

```
$ sudo sfdisk
```